# Custom MySQL query for jquery dataTables

Tags: php, jquery, json, datatables, tabletools

the problem here is the dataTables pagination is not working
this is the script i created that outputs json from the database

```
include( "../database.php" );

$q = $dbh->prepare("SELECT r.studid, r.firstname, r.middlename, r.lastname, r.Enrolling, c.courseid,c.code, s.status,s.dateapproved,s.approvedby FROM pcc_registration r, pcc_courses c, pcc_studentsubj s  WHERE c.courseid= r.Enrolling AND s.studentid=r.studid AND  r.status=? AND s.status=? GROUP BY r.studid");
$q->execute(array(1,2));
$rows = array();
$i = 1;
while ($r = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM, PDO::FETCH_ORI_NEXT, PDO::FETCH_COLUMN)){
    $rows[] = array(
        "DT_RowId" => "row_".$i,
        "reg" => array(
                "studid" => $r[0],
                "firstname" => $r[1],
                "middlename" => $r[2],
                "lastname" => $r[3],
                "course" => $r[6],
                "dateapproved" => $r[8],
                "approvedby" => $r[9]
            ),
    );
    $i++;
}
$rt = (STRING) $q->rowCount();
$data = array(
        "draw" => 2,
        "recordsTotal" => $rt,
        "recordsFiltered" => $rt,
        "data" => $rows
    );
echo json_encode($data);
```

and this is the javascript that outputs the json encoded data to the page

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {  
    $('#dataTables-example').DataTable( {
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: {
            url: "includes/php/approvedSched.php",
            type: "POST"
        },
        "deferRender": true,
        columns: [
            {data: "reg.studid"},
            {data: "reg.lastname"},
            {data: "reg.firstname"},
            {data: "reg.middlename"},
            {data: "reg.course"},
            {data: "reg.dateapproved"},
            {data: "reg.approvedby"},
            {data: "reg.studid"},
        ],
        tableTools: {
            sRowSelect: "os",
            aButtons: [
                // {sExtends: "editor_edit", editor: editor},
                // {sExtends: "editor_remove", editor: editor}
            ]
        }
    } );

    });

}(jQuery));
```

any answer or solution to this problem is appreciated =)

Answer (score 1):

http://datatables.net/manual/server-side

http://coderexample.com/datatable-demo-server-side-in-phpmysql-and-ajax/

this links is a better help for custom server side with mySQL

Answer (score 0):

Where is the problem exactly? Is it just the DataTable pagination, or is it related with the MySQL query? I mean, does it show the rows and the problem is just the pagination, or it doesn't show anything at all?

I had some issues 'transferring' the query result from php to js as JSON (I'm a complete web programming noob), but DataTables' pagination didn't gave me any problem...